# In duckdb, how do I generate a range of timestamps between a start date column and an end date column?

Tags: duckdb

I have a start date column & an end date column ...

| start_timestamp | stop_timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |

... & I want to transform it to ...

| timestamp | start_timestamp | stop_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 00:00 | 2012-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2012-01-01 00:10 | 2012-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2019-12-31 23:50 | 2018-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |

(i.e. I'd like to generate a range of timestamps of interval 10 minutes between start & end dates so that I can merge with a timestamp column)

In `PostgreSQL` I can do ...

```sql
with date_range as (
  select start_timestamp, date('2020-01-01') as stop_timestamp
  from
    pg_catalog.generate_series('2012-01-01', '2020-01-01', interval '3 years') as start_timestamp
)
select
  timestamp,
  start_timestamp,
  stop_timestamp
from
  date_range,
  pg_catalog.generate_series(start_timestamp, stop_timestamp, interval '10 minutes') as timestamp
```

I tried to mimic this in `duckdb` via ...

```sql
%%sql
WITH date_range AS (
    SELECT
      generate_series as start_timestamp,
      CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE) as stop_timestamp
    FROM
      generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2012-01-01', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01', INTERVAL '3 years')
)
SELECT
  start_timestamp,
  stop_timestamp,
  timestamp
FROM
  date_range,
  generate_series(TIMESTAMP start_timestamp, TIMESTAMP stop_timestamp, INTERVAL '10 minute')
```

... but no luck!

I also tried a `RECURSIVE CTE` as per https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/query_syntax/with

Any advice?

(See https://duckdb.org/ for a `Jupyter` setup guide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting any errors?

This works for me:

```
with date_range as (
  select
     generate_series as start_timestamp,
     '2020-01-01'::date as stop_timestamp
  from
     generate_series(timestamp '2012-01-01', timestamp '2020-01-01', interval '3 years')
)
select
  unnest(generate_series(start_timestamp, stop_timestamp, interval '10 minutes')) as timestamp,
  start_timestamp,
  stop_timestamp
from
  date_range
```

EDIT: I added @jqurious suggestion to include `unnest`

Comment: This does indeed work, however, it does not produce data in my desired format!  The original data is 3x3 & the data from this operation is also 3x3 as it yields a list of timestamps like `[2012-01-01 00:00:00, 2012-01-01 00:10:00, 201...` for each `start_timestamp` & `stop_timestamp`.  I'm looking for a reshaped `DataFrame` of one row for every timestamp between each `start_timestamp`:`stop_timestamp` as in `Postgres`

Comment: Ah okay - I missed that part. It sounds like you want to `unnest()` the list? `select unnest(generate_series(start_timestamp, stop_timestamp, interval '10 minutes')) as timestamp`